# How to obtain the same result as <%= var %> without the =?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the Rails views, I regularly find lines like:

```
<%= my_var %>
```

What if I had a slightly more complex situation and I needed to trigger the printing with plain code instead of <%= %>?

Example:

```
<% .....
puts my_var
%>
```

I guess is a silly question but bear with me, I'm a ruby beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [documentation of ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)

In <% %> you put expressions that are not for printing out.

In <%= %> you put code for printing out.

Example:

```
<% if @cost < 10 %>
  <b>Only <%= @cost %>!!!</b>
<% else %>
  Call for a price, today!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper method which is much more cleaner.

Comment: one must use helpers method to keep views clean